# SQL: SELECT DISTINCT not returning distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, reportbuilder3.0

The code below is supposed to return unique records in the lp_num field from the subquery to then be used in the outer query, but I am still getting multiples of the lp_num field. A ReferenceNumber can have multiple ApptDate records, but each lp_num can only have 1 rf_num. That's why I tried to retrieve unique lp_num records all the way down in the subquery, but it doesn't work. I am using Report Builder 3.0.

**Current Output**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXQTI.jpg)

The desired output would be to have only unique records in the lp_num field. This is because each value in the lp_num field is a pallet, one single pallet. the info to the right is when it arrived (ApptDate) and what the reference number is for the delivery (ref_num). Therefore, it makes no sense for a pallet to have multiple receipt dates...it can only arrive once...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.item,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lot,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lp_num,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_num,
                (MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dbo.CW_CheckInOut.ApptDate,101))) as appt_date_only,
                dbo.CW_CheckInOut.ApptTime,
                dbo.item.description,
                dbo.item.u_m,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.qty,
                (CASE
                    WHEN dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type = 'F'
                    THEN 'Produced internally'
                         ELSE
                             (CASE
                                 WHEN dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type = 'R'
                                  THEN 'Received from outside'
                             END)
                          END
               ) as original_source

FROM
     dbo.ISW_LPTrans
     INNER JOIN dbo.CW_Dock_Schedule ON LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_num)) = dbo.CW_Dock_Schedule.ReferenceNumber
     INNER JOIN dbo.CW_CheckInOut ON dbo.CW_CheckInOut.TruckID = dbo.CW_Dock_Schedule.TruckID
     INNER JOIN dbo.item ON dbo.item.item = dbo.ISW_LPTrans.item

WHERE
     (dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type = 'R') AND
      --CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dbo.CW_CheckInOut.ApptDate,101) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_date,101) AND             
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lp_num IN
     (SELECT DISTINCT
        dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lp_num
          FROM
             dbo.ISW_LPTrans
             INNER JOIN dbo.item ON dbo.ISW_LPTrans.item = dbo.item.item
             INNER JOIN dbo.job ON dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_num = dbo.job.job AND dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_line_suf = dbo.job.suffix
         WHERE 
            (dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type = 'W' OR dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type = 'I') AND
            dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_num IN
            (SELECT
               dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_num
               FROM
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans
                 --INNER JOIN dbo.ISW_LPTrans on dbo.ISW_LPTrans.
               WHERE
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.item LIKE @item AND
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lot LIKE @lot AND
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type = 'F'
               GROUP BY
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_num
                  ) AND
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_line_suf IN
              (SELECT
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_line_suf
               FROM
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans
                 --INNER JOIN dbo.ISW_LPTrans on dbo.ISW_LPTrans.
               WHERE
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.item LIKE @item AND
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lot LIKE @lot AND
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type = 'F'
               GROUP BY
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_line_suf
                  )             
               GROUP BY
                 dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lp_num
               HAVING
                 SUM(dbo.ISW_LPTrans.qty) < 0
                )
              GROUP BY
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.item,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lot,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.trans_type,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lp_num,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.ref_num,
                dbo.CW_CheckInOut.ApptDate,
                dbo.CW_CheckInOut.ApptTime,
                dbo.item.description,
                dbo.item.u_m,
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.qty         
            ORDER BY
                dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lp_num
```

Comment: Just because the inner subquery contains unique results do not mean the outer query will similarly be restricted. You must use `DISTINCT` (or `GROUP BY`) in the outer query too, as appropriate.

Comment: For example, if the inner query returns (`1, 2, 3`) the outer query can still contain (`1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3`) and that's okay, because each outer-query value is in the inner query value.

Comment: Using `GROUP BY` in the outer query forces me to put all of the outer fields in that clause (otherwise it gives me an error), therefore nullifying the ability to return unique lp_num values because for every lp_num -> ref_num -> apt_date_only there are 3 apt_date_only for every 1 lp_num (for certain records).

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` in the outer query gives me an error: Incorrect syntax near the word `DISTINCT`. This occurred when I added `DISTINCT` directly to the left of dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lp_num (with a space of course)

Comment: @Dai forgot to tag you

Comment: Add the distinct to after the `select` at the very top,not before the table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that still returns the multiple records of lp_num field because for each lp_num record there can be multiple records for the ApptDate field.

Comment: show us the output you are getting and show us the output that you expect, we can help.

Comment: @Adish screenshot added

Comment: So which AppDate do you want to show? first ? last? if you only want to show one you need to pick which one to show?

Comment: You basically put MAX or MIN around the field that has 'duplicates' and group by the rest. There is no way to avoid that.

Comment: Could it be that you are missing something when joining check_in_out with dock_schedule so that you will have an entry for all deliveries by this truck instead of just one?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried using `MIN` but the output looks the same. I updated my code to show what I did.

Comment: @maraca wait what do you mean? I might have forgotten a `JOIN`???

Comment: What is the schema for CW_CheckInOut table? You are doing "INNER JOIN dbo.CW_CheckInOut ON dbo.CW_CheckInOut.TruckID = dbo.CW_Dock_Schedule.TruckID". This will bring up multiple records for the truck and some of those may not relate to the same ref_num. AS @maraca has pointed out, you seem to be missing an additional clause on this join.

Comment: Yep, you're right @Adish . For the last lp_num record (342020180) in the column (just as an example), there are 3 truck IDs for its reference number in CW_Dock_Schedule. For that lp_num (342020180) I need it to return ref_num 15-0001968 and ApptDate 10/16/2015.

Comment: Let me know if you got it right or if you need more help.

Comment: @Adish I can't figure out how to make it ignore that CW_Dock_Schedule could have multiple TruckID for each ReferenceNumber....

Comment: post the schema of the tables used in the query

Comment: @Adish what does that mean? What is the schema of a table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95105/discussion-between-adish-and-whatwhatwhat).

Comment: You'll also have to MIN on ApptTime, in fact everything that comes from CheckInOut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell - the way you use `DISTINCT` is logically wrong from SQL perspective.

Your `DISTINCT` is in an `IN` subquery in the `WHERE` clause - and at that point of code it has absolutely no effect (except from the performance penalty). Think on it - if the outer query returns non-unique values of `dbo.ISW_LPTrans.lp_num` (which obvioulsy happens) those values can still be within the distinct values of the `IN` subquery - the `IN` does not enforce a 1-to-1 match, it only enforces the fact that the outer query values are within the inner values, but they can match multiple times. So it is definitely not `DISTINCT`'s fault.

I would go through the following check steps:

- **See if there is insufficient `JOIN ON` condition(s)** in the outer `FROM` section that leads to data multiplication (e.g. if a table has primary-to-foreign key relation on several columns, but you join on one of them only etc.).
- **Check which of the sources contains non-distinct records** in the outer `FROM` section - then either cleanse your source, or adjust the JOIN condition and / or the WHERE clause so that you only pick distinct & correct records. In fact you might need to `SELECT DISTINCT` in the `FROM` sections - there it would make much more sense.

Comment: Got it. dbo.ISW_LPTrans has the field Uf_TruckID which I needed to `INNER JOIN` on dbo.CW_Dock_Schedule.TruckID (the primray key of that table...)